# Convert large text block to json block

Tags: json, bash, awk, jira

I have a BASH script that attempts to capture the output of build/deployment logs and insert them into a Jira ticket using Jira's REST API and CURL:

```
curl -v  -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data "@header.json" \
--data "@log.txt" \
--data "@footer.json" \
-H "Authorization:Basic ABC123!@#" \
https://companyname.jira.com/rest/api/latest/issue/FOO-1234/comment
```

My problem is that the logs contain all manner of JSON tokens, which causes the insert to fail. Is there a way from BASH to clean up the text blob before posting to escape out all the illegal characters? Or a way to say "don't parse anything in this block" or similar? Worst case, I'll write some really scary AWK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all I needed to escape were the quotes and to convert newlines to \n. I used the following sed actions:

```
sed -inplace 's/\"/\\\"/g' log.txt
sed -inplace ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\n/g' log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Once upon a time I used this code snippet for sending POST data using curl.

```
urlquote() {
    echo -ne "$1" | xxd -plain | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/\(..\)/%\1/g'
}
```

It works great with unicode stuff as well. Maybe this is going to help.